# DDD deal with distributed status accross domains

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design

Let's say we have a simple food delivery app. Where client order the food, then restaurant start preparing the food and gives it to the courier who delivery it to the client.

So here we have three different domains and each of this domain have their own order:

- **client** - here client order the food and have the status of the food `in preparation | in delivery | delivered`
- **restaurant** - here restaurant got its order and has their own status `in queue | in preparation | ready to pick up`
- **courier** - courier has only two status `delivering | delivered`

Moreover each of this domain has their own price and other attribute about order:

- **client** - total price (food price + delivery cost + fee)
- **restaurant** - price of food, time of production to give a hind to the client when food will be delivery
- **courier** - cost of delivery

All I want to highlight is that each of the domain has its own order aggregate, so according to `DDD` we have to keep it in different aggregates even in different microservices:

- **client** - `/orders/:id` provides the general status of the order and total price to the client.
- **restaurant** - `/restaurants/:restaurantId/orders/:id` provides the status of the food in **restaurant** domain and cost.
- **courier** - `/couriers/:courierId/orders/:id` provides information how much courier earn from this order and how long it took to delivier

But now I met another problem, because **client** order combines information from other domains (is food still in restaurant or it's being delivery) so I have to gather this information when client asks about its order, but it means that client doesn't have its domain (its own aggregate, total price, discount etc), but if I create order aggregate for the client then I will not keep all information about order in one place (when restaurant give the food to the courier it should also change status of the order in **client** domain) what is not really according to microservices, because we keep information about the same order in different microservices.

Should I just create one order domain or should I split it to different domain and make these domains communicate between, when something will change in one domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One useful approach is to leverage domain events.  When the restaurant's view of the state of the order changes, an event describing that change is published.  The other services can then update their model of the event (assuming that that change is relevant to that service).

So for instance, we might have:

- user creates order via the client service => `OrderCreated` event emitted
- restaurant service consumes `OrderCreated` event, translates the order for the restaurant (e.g. uses the prices which the delivery app pays the restaurant vs. the prices the delivery app charges the user) => `OrderSentToRestaurant` event emitted
- courier service consumes `OrderCreated` and begins trying to figure out which courier will be assigned the order and the approximate transport time from pickup to delivery => `DeliveryLatencyEstimateMade` event emitted
- client service consumes `OrderSentToRestaurant` and updates its order status (for presentation to the user) to `in preparation`
- courier service ignores `OrderSentToRestaurant`
- restaurant service ignores `DeliveryLatencyEstimateMade` event
- client service consumes `DeliveryEstimateLatencyEstimateMade` and updates its model (delivery time remains `unknown`)
- restaurant informs restaurant service of expected completion time => `OrderReadyForPickupAt` event emitted
- courier service consumes `OrderReadyForPickup`, refines courier assignment decisions
- client service consumes `OrderReadyForPickupAt` event, combines with the latest latency estimate to present a predicted delivery time to the user

and so forth.  Each service is autonomous and in control of its data representation and free to ignore or interpret the events as it sees fit.  Note that this implies eventual consistency (the restaurant service will know about when the order is expected to be ready for pickup before the courier or client services know about that), though microservice autonomy already effectively ruled out strong consistency.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at aggregate design in each bounded context (BC), you have to include only the data required to provide the functionality that belongs to that BC. The fact that the restaurant endpoint needs to return some extra data is not a good enough reason to add that data to the order aggregate in that BC.

You can resolve the need for more data in different ways:

1. The API client can call multiple endpoints to fetch all the data it needs
2. The API can implement Data Aggregation, by internally querying multiple BCs/microservices and combining them to produce a single more complete response object
3. Create Read models, which store data from multiple sources into a single "table" in a way that simplifies querying and returning this data. This approach is more complex, but it's very useful when you need to filter and sort by fields belonging to multiple BCs, which is not possible with the previous two approaches.

Another consideration to make is double-checking if your boundaries are correct. Do you really need a Client BC? What business logic does it implement?  Maybe Orders are created directly into Restaurant and there is no Client order? Client order could just be a "façade" providing all Restaurant orders belonging to a single client Id?

As a final note, I completely agree with Levi Ramsey's answer that events are the right way to coordinate the different aggregates. They would also be used to create the read models I mentioned above.